# aws ec2 can reach to httpServer, but cannot fastify server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fastify

I have two server. First one is `fastify` server, and second one is Nodejs built-in `http` server. All of them is working well in local development environment.

But when I deploy these to **AWS EC2** instance, I cannot reach to `fastify` server. Each use same port. I stopeed one when another one executed.

Do you know what is the problem? I opened in-bound security group port 3000, I think this is not security group or firewall problem because I can reach to one of server.

**fastify server**

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({})

// Declare a route
fastify.get('/', async (request, reply) => {
  return { hello: true }
})

// Run the server!
const start = async () => {
  try {
    const port = 3000
    await fastify.listen({ port })
    console.log(' Fastify Server Listening on Port ', port)
  } catch (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

start()
```

**Nodejs built-in server**

```
var http = require('http')

//create a server object:
http
  .createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.write('Hello World!') //write a response to the client
    res.end() //end the response
  })
  .listen(3000) //the server object listens on port 8080
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really annoying library

```
await fastify.listen({ port: 3000, host: '0.0.0.0' })
```

Comment: It is a "secure by default" setting